# Error when accessing Admin panel using xampp

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an error with my database and application. The program is not registering a new user and also doesn't login with the users already saved in the database. As soon as I try accessing the admin panel an error appears which is

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cman\admin\lib\dbcon.php:8 Stack trace:

> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cman\admin\header.php(45): dbcon()

> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\cman\admin\index.php(1): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')

> #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cman\admin\lib\dbcon.php on line 8.

What might be the problem? I am not so good in PHP and databases and I'm trying to learn.

Comment: All the `mysql_*()` functions were removed in PHP 7. Use `mysqli_*()` instead.

Comment: The application is obviously VERY OLD!  You will have to migrate it to mysqli as @TangentiallyPerpendicular already mentioned.  if it is a bought or downloaded application it is very outdated-  get the last version or use a different one.